# Facebook Messenger is not working on Microsoft Lumia 535 (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: nokia-lumia-535, facebook, internet, messenger

I have been using my Lumia 535 for three months now. everything was working fine until just a few days back when i noticed my Facebook Messenger trying to connect to the WiFi/Mobile Data network but all it does is show me this 
**"Waiting for Network"** everytime i try to connect to Facebook Messenger.i have tried a soft reset,uninstalling the messenger and re-install but to no avail.your help in this regard would be appreciated.i am attaching the screenshot below

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that version of Messenger is no longer supported on Windows Phone 8.1. Here's an official announcement from Facebook stating that various apps would be discontinued on older operating systems, including WP8 as well as older versions of iOS and Android:

[Update on messaging support for older versions of Messenger and Facebook apps](https://messengerblog.com/general-messenger/update-on-support-for-older-versions-of-messenger-and-facebook-apps)

Specifically:

> By the end of March, we will be ending support for messaging on the following older mobile app versions:
>
> - Windows
>
>   - Facebook for Windows Phone.
>   - Messenger for Windows Phone 8 and 8.1.
>   - Facebook for Windows 8 and 8.1 desktop app.

The article also lists a few apps that should work for Windows users:

> - [Facebook for Windows Phone](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/facebook/9wzdncrfj2wl)
> - [Messenger for Windows Phone](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/messenger/9wzdncrf0083)
> - [Facebook for Windows Desktop App](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/facebook/9wzdncrfj2wl)

The second one (Messenger for Windows Phone) looks like it still supports Windows Phone 8.1, but it also requires 2 GB of RAM, so you might not be able to install it on your Lumia 535. If that's the case, you should be able to access Facebook (including the Messenger functionality) through the browser. Alternatively, the Lumia 535 should be eligible for upgrade to Windows 10 Mobile, which would let you use the [new Messenger Beta app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/messenger-beta/9nblggh2t5jk) that doesn't seem to have a RAM requirement.

Comment: Indrek,thanks a lot for all the detailed info about Facebook and how the Messenger is not supported on Windows Phone 8.1 anymore.my facebook application on my Lumia 535 is working but the messenger isn't.i will be using the windows explorer browser to access FB and Messnger for now.can you tell me how i can update my Lumia 535 to Windows 10.i tried the Phone Update option but it just says its up to date after each check.

Comment: @Iftekhar Glad I could help! If this solved your issue, be sure to mark the answer as accepted (by clicking the green checkmark). As for upgrading to Windows 10, you'll need to [Upgrade Advisor app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/upgrade-advisor/9nblggh0f5g4) on your phone. Check [this FAQ page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10599/windows-10-mobile-how-to-get) for more information.

Comment: i will do the needful and see if it can be fixed. thank you.

Comment: Indrek,I have successfully upgraded from 8.1 to Windows 10. Facebook Messenger is now working after installing Upgrade Advisor App on my phone, downloaded Windows 10 from there, installed the new Messenger for Windows 10.it took little more than one and a half hour to finish the whole procedure.thanks a lot again.

Comment: @Iftekhar You're very welcome :)