# Can't log in to Skype lately

Tags: 8.1, skype

I've got Nokia Lumia 636 with Windows Phone 8.1. One of these days it stopped to log in to Skype. I tried to log in with Skype name, and with Microsoft account. Both methods fail. Although, I use Gmail's mailbox for the latter, if that matters. I can log in with both credentials on login.live.com. Why is that? Is there a way to make it work on my phone?

Comment: The solution would be to change phone / OS. I have 1 GB RAM Nokia and made the mistake to upgrade to WIN 10. It had really good user interface, but it was really buggy, restarting apps all the time. Went back to 8.1. Much better - however FB messenger not supported, now Skype... If you are a Nokia fan, there are Android options now. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Skype is no longer supported on Windows Phone 8.1](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/news/item/22052_Skype_no_longer_works_for_Wind.php) as of July 2017. Your options pretty much boil down to the following:

- Upgrade your phone to Windows 10 Mobile (the Lumia 636 is [officially supported](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-10-mobile-specifications#mobile-upgrade-availability); download the [Upgrade Advisor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/upgrade-advisor/9nblggh0f5g4) app to verify eligibility and get started)
- Buy a newer Windows phone running Windows 10 Mobile
- Use another instant messaging app (but note that those might also end WP8.1 support at any time; [Facebook for example has already started doing so](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/14863/1401))
- Switch to Android or iPhone

Comment: Actually, I've got exactly Nokia Lumia 63**6** with 1GB of RAM. It's just that I couldn't find the appropriate tag. Although, that doesn't matter much probably.

Comment: No problem, I've fixed the model name in the question. In the future, you can just leave a note in your post asking someone (a mod or regular user with enough reputation) to create the tag for you, that's preferable to tagging with the wrong model. But the Lumia 636 should actually be eligible for upgrade to Windows 10 Mobile, per [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-10-mobile-specifications). You can download the Upgrade Advisor app from the Store to get started.

Comment: Was trying to resurrect a Lumia 1020 to have as backup phone and was banging my head against the wall for almost an hour trying to get Skype to connect. Thanks for posting the link, as unfortunate as the information is.